# How to store the characters from one string into an array?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, character, console-application

I want to know how to dissect a single string so I can store the characters of the string into an array. Here is what I have:

```
Dim Word, Letters(99) As string

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word: ")

    Word = Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

so say the 'Word' was 'Hello'. I want the array's elements to look like this:

```
Letters(0) = H
Letters(1) = e
Letters(2) = l
Letters(3) = l
Letters(4) = o
```

Thanks.

Comment: search for string.ToCharArray

Comment: A string is basically an array of characters already (or, at least, you can treat it that way in loops, etc.).  What are you trying to do once you have that array?

Comment: I'm just wanting to see how many different combinations you can create with a certain word. I know you could work it out mathematically but i want it to output all the different combinations.

Comment: As @rory.ap points out you can already treat the String `Word` as an array. `Word(0)` is "H"c, `Word(1)` is "e"c, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having two variables, you can call `Word(x)` to retrieve a certain character from the string.

Alternatively, you can define `Letters` as a Char() and then set `Letters` to `Word` to implicitly convert the String to Char().